# How can I create a dynamic ListView in Android that contains images in between a fixed header and footer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, layout-inflater

I'm a beginner to Android development, but not to software development.  I've been looking for tutorials on how to create dynamic ListViews with images and have had some trouble.

The tutorial I followed most closely was #2 on this link (the Custom ArrayAdapter example): http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

This works fine if I remove the header and footer from my layout xml file, but I really need those to be included.  Below I'll post my source from my Activity java file, my custom array adapter java file, and my layout xml file as well as the output.  I think there may be something I'm missing or not understanding about how the layout inflater works.

Thanks for your time.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] MAIN_MENU = 
        new String[] { "ICD-10", "EDUCATION", "NEWS", "SERVICES", "CONTACT" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MAIN_MENU));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    // to contact
    if(selectedValue.equals(MAIN_MENU[4])) {
        contactPressed(v);
    }
    // to icd-10
    else if(selectedValue.equals(MAIN_MENU[0])) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ICDActivity.class));
    }
    // to services
    else if(selectedValue.equals(MAIN_MENU[3])) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class));
    }

}

public void  contactPressed(View v) {       
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.stay);
}

}
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
  public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lvText);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lvImage);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    if (s.equals("ICD-10"))
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_icd10);
    }
    else if(s.equals("EDUCATION"))
    { 
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_education);
    }
    else if(s.equals("NEWS"))
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_news);
    }
    else if(s.equals("SERVICES"))
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_services);
    }
    else if(s.equals("CONTACT"))
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_contact);
    }

    return rowView;
}
 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/custom_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/gray">
</ImageView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_header" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/footer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:onClick="contactPressed"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/footerText" />

</RelativeLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footerLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
        android:padding="5dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <!-- Making a dynamic ListView with images with the two attributes below -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lvImage"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_icd10" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/lvText"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The output I get for this is:**
[image]

**If I comment out the header and footer code in the xml I get:**
[image]

**The goal is for it to look similar to this but with images on the right side of each line:**
[image]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem while searching for another tutorial.  I finally ended up using this tutorial:  http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

My problem was that I tried to replace my ListView with a TextView and ImageView in the same layout.xml file when I should have created my TextView and ImageView in a different layout.xml file.  Below is the final code and the correct output I was looking for.  Thanks!

**list_single.xml** (below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**  (below)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/gray">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_header" />

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/footer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:onClick="contactPressed"
        android:text="@string/footerText" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ImageAdapter.java**  (below)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        if (s.equals("ICD-10"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_icd10);
        }
        else if(s.equals("EDUCATION"))
        { 
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_education);
        }
        else if(s.equals("NEWS"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_news);
        }
        else if(s.equals("SERVICES"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_services);
        }
        else if(s.equals("CONTACT"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_contact);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**  (below)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    static final String[] MAIN_MENU = 
            new String[] { "ICD-10", "EDUCATION", "NEWS", "SERVICES", "CONTACT" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainMenuList);
        list.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, MAIN_MENU));

        // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                String selectedValue = MAIN_MENU[position];

                // to contact
                if(selectedValue.equals(MAIN_MENU[4])) {
                    contactPressed(v);
                }
                // to icd-10
                else if(selectedValue.equals(MAIN_MENU[0])) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ICDActivity.class));
                }
                // to services
                else if(selectedValue.equals(MAIN_MENU[3])) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void  contactPressed(View v) {       
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.stay);
    }

}
```

And the final output (below)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First looks like you have

```
android:layout_above="@id/footerLayout"
android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
```

on your `@+id/scrollableContents`, which is good. But you also have it on the view nested inside it, `@+id/linearList` which is not right. There may be other layout problems but it is hard to tell. In general this layout looks very complex for what you are trying to achieve.

But I'm not sure really what you mean by "dynamic ListView" and it looks like you are trying to re-create the functionality of a listview using a ScrollView. I don't think you should take that approach. The ListView is very flexible and you can use a custom layout for your items.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Is there a way to introduce images using a ListView?  I tried searching for that first and all of the recommendations used 1 TextView and 1 ImageView which they were using to create multiple instances of them programmatically.  That gave them the general look and feel of a simple ListView at least that is how it looked to me.

When I say "dynamic ListView" I merely mean using a TextView to recreate the look of a ListView.

Comment: Also, I agree this layout looks very complex for what I'm trying to achieve.  Would you recommend a different way of going about it?  My aim is to simply add images along the right hand side of each member of my ListView.